# Bookmark locations in videos

Tags: video, media-player, media-manager

I have some exercise videos where I would like to have "bookmarks" at certain points.

What kind of software will let me do that?

Windows/Android (often the same files "synced between devices).

Could also be useful with web-based like Android.

Comment: Do you want it to save the bookmarks to the file? or just in the program's database?

Comment: Anything.  If it is a file, it could ba accessed from different machines, perhaps from different apps.

Comment: Can you please clarify "often the same files "synced between devices" and "Could also be useful with web-based like Android."?

Comment: I keep all important filed in Dropbox.  From my Android device I can then access them from the Dropbox website.  Sometimes I also have a copy stored locally on Android.

Comment: (The point is that if bookmarks are stored in a file, they can be synced to other environments)

Comment: The only solution I have found is Potplayer (Windows only) It has has bookmark possibilities, and the bookmarks can be stored in a file located with the video. I think the format is proprietary, but you can read out the time of the bookmarks in seconds. (I tried to put this as an answer, but it was deleted)